# Telerik Open Access error on string with 8000 characters

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-express, nvarchar, telerik-open-access

I'm trying to save 8,000 characters to a SQL Server Express database table, and this may be smaller or larger in the future, and I'm getting an exception saying that the data will be truncated.

I've already set the column to `varchar(max)` and don't know if there is another setting for the ORM itself.

Any help is appreciated

```
Update failed: Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.sql.SQLException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.CommandWrapper.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.Runtime.Logging.LoggingDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.Adonet2Generic.Impl.CommandImp.ExecuteReader()
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.Adonet2Generic.Impl.PreparedStatementImp.executeUpdate(Nullable`1 commandTimeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.Adonet2Generic.Impl.PreparedStatementImp.executeUpdate(Nullable`1 commandTimeout)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.conn.PooledPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Nullable`1 commandTimeout)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.RelationalStorageManager.generateUpdates(OID oid, Int32 index, ClassMetaData cmd, PersistGraph graph, Int32[] fieldNos, Boolean haveNewObjects, CharBuf s, BatchControlInfo batchControl, Boolean previousInserts)
Row: GenericOID@bd4840c1 TokenRequest TokenID=ae428dc3-5815-42ac-bbd6-e4a3f8e87132
UPDATE [TokenRequest] SET [PI]=?, [ReqState]=?, [second_message_date]=?, [second_message_j_s_o_n]=?, [TI]=? WHERE [TokenID] = ? AND [ReqState] is null AND [second_message_date]=?
(set event logging to all to see parameter values) Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.sql.SQLException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.CommandWrapper.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.Runtime.Logging.LoggingDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.Adonet2Generic.Impl.CommandImp.ExecuteReader()
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.Adonet2Generic.Impl.PreparedStatementImp.executeUpdate(Nullable`1 commandTimeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Telerik.OpenAccess.RT.Adonet2Generic.Impl.PreparedStatementImp.executeUpdate(Nullable`1 commandTimeout)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.conn.PooledPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Nullable`1 commandTimeout)
   at OpenAccessRuntime.Relational.RelationalStorageManager.generateUpdates(OID oid, Int32 index, ClassMetaData cmd, PersistGraph graph, Int32[] fieldNos, Boolean haveNewObjects, CharBuf s, BatchControlInfo batchControl, Boolean previousInserts)
```

Comment: Is there anywhere from within the visual designer where you can see what the column is set to? Data-type that is?

Comment: @kreepN The designer says I'm using varchar(max)

Comment: Are you setting any other columns to anything during this update? It looks like it?: "[PI]=?, [ReqState]=?, [second_message_date]=?, [second_message_j_s_o_n]=?, [TI]=?".  Perhaps one of those is not the required length in the db to support the inserted value.

Comment: @kreepn yes the problem is with the column reqstate. If I don't set the value than everything is fine.  I inspected the coin and that is the column with 8000 chars. I right clicked on the designer and made sure the column was varchar max.  I also deleted and recreated the table.

Comment: The next step would I guess be to check the value of said column and verify it really is only 8000: http://documentation.telerik.com/openaccess-orm/developers-guide/tracing-and-logging/openaccess-tasks-tracing-and-logging-enable-log . Turn that on and you should be able to grab the value, copy it out, and paste into a text editor to check the length.

Answer (score -2):

@makerofthings7, my best guess about the re-appearance of the error after the fix is that the model and the database are not in synchronous. 
It seems that you have modified the table in the storage model in Visual Designer and in order to complete the fix, I would suggest to you to run the [Update Database From Model](http://documentation.telerik.com/openaccess-orm/feature-reference/tools/update-database-from-model-wizard/model-tools-updata-database-from-model-overview) wizard and to transfer the change in the database.

I hope this helps.